# How to send data in csv format from web api controller to react client side for creating visualisations

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I have the following code to convert the EF output to CSV file (and save it to the server side and then return it):

```
   List<LearningActionMonitoringDTO> results = _context
       .LearningActionProgressUpdates
       .Include(la => la.LearningAction)
       .Where(la => la.LearningActionId == actionId)
       .Select(la => new LearningActionMonitoringDTO
       {
           Title = la.LearningAction.Title,
           Progress = la.Progress,
           ProgressDate = la.DateCreated.ToString("g"),

       }).ToList();

   using (var csv = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter("CSVfiles/Actors.csv")))
   {
       csv.WriteRecords(results);
   }

   FileInfo f = new FileInfo("CSVfiles/Actors.csv");
   return f;
```

I wonder if I could return the `results` in CSV format without first saving it to the server. I need the data in CSV file to feed into a React component for creating some charts. Any help?

Comment: Sure, you can just return it verbatim, and set the content-type of the response to `text/csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment, and some code from the author of `CsvWriter` (assuming it's the same CSV library), to write it to a string, you do the following:

```
using( var stream = new MemoryStream() )
using( var reader = new StreamReader( stream ) )
using( var writer = new StreamWriter( stream ) )
using( var csv = new CsvWriter( writer ) )
{
    csv.WriteRecords( results);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

(From [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/128))

Now that you have your CSV file as a chunk of text, we can return it from a Controller thusly:

```
public ActionResult DownloadCSV()
{
    return Content(yourCsvString, "text/csv");
}
```

Comment: I have a question. I wonder if I could send the resulting csv as string? The thing is I want to return an object, inside this object I want to include the CSV string as well as other information. I tried `ExecuteResult` but could not get it work. Any help?

Comment: @renakre Can you ask that as a separate question, including any supporting details - that way the wider-community will see it :)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144160/how-to-put-content-object-in-controller-inside-another-object-to-be-returned