# How to put Content object (in Controller) inside another object to be returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have the following code that returns a `List` in `CVS` format using `Content`, which is working fine.

```
public ContentResult LearningActionMonitoringPageDataAsync(int actionId)
{
    //other code
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
     using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
     {
           csv.WriteRecords(resultsToReturn);
           writer.Flush();
           stream.Position = 0;
           text = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }

      return Content(text, "text/csv");
}
```

But, what I want to do is, instead of returning the `Content`, putting it inside another object which contains some other information to be returned, something like this:

```
List <PageData> pageData = new List <PageData> {
    CSVcontent = Content(text, "text/csv"),
    PageTitle = "Abc",
    //some other data to display on the page
}
```

However, I could not manage to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by returning an `ActionResult` with the `Json` method, e.g:

```
List <PageData> pageData = new List <PageData> {
    CSVcontent = Content(text, "text/csv"),
    PageTitle = "Abc",
    //some other data to display on the page
}

return Json(pageData, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

Note that if your CSV data is now not the "main" return from the HTTP method, there's no need to have the `Content()` call, you can just assign it directly, e.g.:

```
`CSVContent = text`
```

But it will be up the client to work with that data.  Using `Json()` will automatically set the content type appropriate for `JSON`.